# Why are soap bubbles attracted to a charged PVC pipe?

Tags: electricity, charge

As demonstrated in trick #4 in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViZNgU-Yt-Y

A Soap bubble is attracted to a charged PVC pipe, my question is why is it so?
My guess is that soap bubbles are ionized due to their chemical properties and thus a positively charged PVC pipe attracts the bubble, is my speculation incorrect?

Comment: As the title of the video says, it is due to static electricity

Comment: @XcoderX, I am aware that it is due to static electricity but what exactly are the forces of attraction taking place in this experiment and what's their source? Your comment doesn't exactly answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static electricity is when two objects of different charges attract each other.  The PVC pipe, upon being rubbed, gains electrons from the cloth it was rubbed with.  The soap bubbles, which has a positive charge attracts the PVC pipe.

Comment: Please upvote too if it helps